# Import other typescript modules

Tags: typescript, node-modules

I am trying to import from typescript file, which is in node_modules. That file is not transpiled and uses typescript syntax:

`user.ts:`

```
export const getUserFromToken = (token: string) => {
  return axios.get('/user', {
    headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
  }).then(({ data }) => data)
}
```

I'm importing like this: `import { getUserFromToken } from 'common-files/api/user'`, and `common-files` is a module registered in package.json.

When trying to compile, I get:

```
../commons/api/user.ts
Module parse failed: C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\xxxx\commons\api\user.ts 
Unexpected token (9:38)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| export const getUserFromToken = (token: string) => {
|   return axios.get('/user', {
|     headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
```

Which leads, me to believe, that it's not compiling the ts file, because when I remove string type, it becomes a valid es6 file, and it starts correctly.

In my `tsconfig.json` file I have:

```
"exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "build",
  "scripts",
  "acceptance-tests",
  "webpack",
  "jest",
  "src/setupTests.ts"
]
```

I was thinking, maybe to exclude node_modules, except that package `common-files`, but don't know how to do that. Is there a good way to achieve what I want at all?

Comment: I'm assuming this is a custom module? Modules need to do their own compiling and publish both a .js and a .d.ts. The issue you're seeing here is indeed that tsc isn't compiling the file (how would it know where to put it) and then webpack (?) is resolving the import to the .ts file for some reason...

Comment: You can include ts files without transpiling if you use ts-node instead of node.

Answer (score 2):

@ShaunLuttin answered the question for the general case. My problem was because I use create-react-app with typescript scripts, and their webpack configuration does not allow usage of raw typescript files from modules. I decided to transpile all my files, and generate a build, that could be used as a module. It worked, however I had make sure not to include anything that works only in node environment when working with frontend projects.

Answer (score 1):

> **Aside:** What you are trying to do is unconventional. Usually, node projects install modules that have already been transpiled into JavaScript.

With that being said, here is a setup that works for you and [a demo on GitHub.](https://github.com/bigfont/StackOverflow/tree/master/typescript-create-and-use-untranspiled-modules) Since your use case in unconventional, the solution is complex.

**Directory structure** > Notice the `index.ts` file inside the `common-files` directory. It has two purposes. First, it will list files that we want TypeScript to transpile. Second, once it is transpiled, the `index.js` file will tell Node that the `common-files` folder is a module. [The Node documentation on Folders as Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules) explains how Node resolves modules.

```
node_modules    
  common-files
    api
      user.ts
    index.ts     <---- This file has two primary purposes.
index.ts        
package.json    
tsconfig.json
```

**node_modules/common-files/api/user.ts** > This file contains a declaration that we want to use in your application.

```
export const getUserFromToken = (token: string) => {
    console.log("Getting the user for token " + token);
}
```

**node_modules/common-files/index.ts** > According to NodeJS defaults, this index.ts file is the main file of your `common-files` module. As previously mentioned, the main file is also going to import each of the declarations that we want to transpile.

```
import "./api/user";
```

**index.ts** > This file represents the application that you are building. We can import any of the transpiled declarations that the `common-files` module exports.

```
import { getUserFromToken } from "common-files/api/user";

getUserFromToken("some-token");
```

**package.json** > Note that there is nothing special in your application's node package file. That said, if you used `npm install` to install the `common-files` package, then we would have `common-files` listed in the `dependencies` section.

```
{
  "dependencies": { }, 
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json** > The TypeScript configuration is somewhat complex, because your `common-files` module needs to be transpiled, and we want to exclude everything else inside node_modules. The [tsconfig documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) has more details on how files, include, and exclude interact.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "files": [
    "node_modules/common-files/index.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

The console output for the above setup looks like this:

```
> .\node_modules\.bin\tsc
> node index.js
Getting the user for token some-token
```

Comment: You're saying this is unconventional, maybe there is a conventional way to achieve what I want? I want two separate packages share some code, and so I've moved that code to the npm package and locally import them in each of the projects. There comes the problem of that npm package not being transpiled when using in other packages.

Comment: @VincasStonys The answer's aside states the conventional approach.

Comment: I have sat down, and went to steps you suggested, but they didn't make any difference, as I'm getting the same error. Maybe my directory structure is invalid in some way, or other configuration is intervening... If you feel like helping, here is my repo link: https://github.com/vincaslt/language-exchange/tree/EnvFix with the fixes according to your answer

Comment: @VincasStonys Sorry to hear that the steps did not work for you. Have you been able to use the demo that I posted in GitHub? If so, did that demo work for you?

Comment: I have used your example alone, and it worked. I have set up a separate new project, that would use your suggestions and it worked... However on the project in question, I use create-react-app with typescript config, from here: https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript It seems that their webpack config does not transpile node_modules, and they explicitly state in webpack config file's comments that packages must be transpiled beforehand... I suppose I will be ejecting and tweaking the project, because transpiling and writing typedefs for the commons package seems cumbersome

Comment: Do you think it could work if I compiled the commons project first, before using it? I tried running `tsc` on commons, and it generated .js files, but when used in the other project, it still tries to import and use .ts files, so the same error remains...

Comment: @VincasStonys If I were you, I would compose a second StackOverflow question. Don't change this first question; rather, write a second question that uses what you have learned from the first question. The second question might lead to answers that lead you closer to your goal.